# Why does Typescript treat `object.hasOwnProperty("key")` as essentially different from `"key" in object`

Tags: typescript

```
declare const action: { total: number } | { };
declare const defavlt: 200;

const total = (action.hasOwnProperty("total")) ? action.total : defavlt;
```

results in the following TS error for `action.total`:

```
Property 'total' does not exist on type '{ type: "NEW_CONVERSATION_LIST" | "UPDATE_CONVERSATION_LIST_ADD_BOTTOM" | "UPDATE_CONVERSATION_LIST_ADD_TOP"; list: IDRArray<RestConversationMember>; total: number | undefined; } | ... 13 more ... | { ...; }'.
  Property 'total' does not exist on type '{ type: "UPDATE_URL_STATE"; updateObj: IMessagingUrlState; }'.ts(2339)
```

Whereas

```
const total = ("total" in action) ? action.total : defavlt
```

works. 
Is there a rational for TS treating both cases differently?

Comment: Afaik not. The difference I know, `in` does take the prototype into account whereas `hasOwnProperty` doesn't. Furthermore I have problems reproducing your kind of issue. Please see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iZBvAWAChlkwsw4AbAfgC5kQBXAWwCNoBuYgX2OIQ4AzmGSJMOBugm4AvPl78igkCLIVqAeRAp5ACnHYQAOgAWcIZoDuIAApQsAB2hgAnnoBE5SlQ8BKP2QaMQwjY29qZAYABm4iAWFRCKoAFSssZH0vDV9kUBCZQODDHHCcqORYpWoXTxSc7QgGD2QAanUfRrbkFoBaXuR6nzSsZu7kkb9OIA

Comment: @r3dst0rm, I'm aware that hasOwnProperty doesn't take into account the prototype. Interesting that your demo doesn't reproduce the issue. Probably since it's TS version 3.7.2, while our project uses TS 3.5.3.

Comment: @r3dst0rm, downgrading your demo to 3.5.1 didn't reproduce the issue. Unfortunately I can't paste a screenshot. Here's a link https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoVymsDeSYhfg41n5lkItLwLsiMqfQ?e=g84Jy0

Comment: That's a bummer. What you could try is to create a function with a type guard that checks for the existence: `const hasOwnProp = <T extends {}>(obj: T, prop: string): obj is T => obj && obj.hasOwnProperty(prop);` and use it like: `hasOwnProp(action, "total") ? action.total : default;`

Comment: Please consider editing the above code to constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [ask].  The type of `action` is relevant missing information.

Comment: @jcalz, THX. Do you find this better?

Comment: Not really, sorry. [Observe](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIILMA9iZBvAWAChlSwsw4AbAfgC5k4QBPZYgX2JgFcQNtcAcwhgAKhWoAKRJhwN0skAEpCJUlBHcouafxwA6ABZwAzgHkA7iAAKULAAdoYZpIBE5SlVdKlNRnpB9D2pkBgATCHhuKjAOYiA); it doesn't give the error you're describing, and `default` is a reserved word which cannot be used as an identifier.  I've already answered the question below with a code link at the bottom, using `declare const action: { total: number } | { specialK: number };` as the type, which does reproduce the issue.  Good luck!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the issue [microsoft/TypeScript#10485](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10485), it was suggested for the `in` operator to act as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) which can be used to filter unions; this was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#15256](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256)  and [released with TypeScript 2.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#type-guards-inferred-from--in-operator).

This was not done for `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`; if you really feel strongly about this, you might want to [file a suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=Feature_request.md&title=ME+WANT+HASOWNPROPERTY+TYPE+GUARD+PLEEZ) for it, noting that a [similar suggestion (microsoft/TypeScript#18282)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18282) was declined because it was asking for the more controversial narrowing of the *key* and not the *object*... and some people have wanted [both (microsoft/TypeScript#20363)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20363).  And there's no guarantee the suggestion would be accepted.

Luckily for you, though, you don't have to wait for this to be implemented upstream.  Unlike an operator like `in`, the `hasProperty()` method is just a library signature that can be altered to act as a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) function.  What's more, you don't even have to touch the [standard library definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L137); you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) to augment the `Object` interface with your own signature for `hasOwnProperty()`:

```
// declare global { // need this declaration if in a module
interface Object {
  hasOwnProperty<K extends PropertyKey>(key: K): this is Record<K, unknown>;
}
// } // need this declaration if in a module
```

This definition says that when you check `obj.hasOwnProperty("someLiteralKey")`, a `true` result implies that `obj` is assignable to `{someLiteralKey: unknown}`, while a `false` result does not.  This definition might not be perfect and there are probably quite a few edge cases (e.g., what should `obj.hasOwnProperty(Math.random()<0.5?"foo":"bar")` imply?  what should `obj.hasOwnProperty("foo"+"bar")` imply? they will do weird things) but it works for your example:

```
const totalIn = ("total" in action) ? action.total : defavlt; // okay
const totalOwnProp = (action.hasOwnProperty("total")) ? action.total : defavlt; // okay
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBMFMGMBsEMBOlQHNYHsBG9agN6gigB2kk4oALgBYCWAzhDAovFXRiaHQGY-d4oALYZwAV1iQAsACg6JKpES940FAHksAKxhUCc0KBrwGGgO4kACogwAHZVQCeAHgDSoSAA8lJcExt7Ryc3SCcAPgAKAGswgC5QNwBKBNpGHiYAJRgMRHB3ABpQcRJokgxLcIBuOQBfOWJaojAyCmp6Jig4JHZObj4BUCFRCSk5OS7WFGguBn01Di4EwioMKlwEknFhLGVQJoAfAlAGB2g6XDdN7d3EfZrZSaRp2f0oVQA3WCoEgCYAFgADA9QHIZiQ5tQ1rgAJLcAC8oEiACJVutYMjBgs+klQAB+IbQRYkAB0aNwoAS73gXyoVWaoAw0XgTjBryh6Is1lsdlAiMi2K4JJMZksgQciGcKPJGKSuIJgtJMspzE+33pxCZLLkQA)

Comment: This is a bit suspicious when testing a key of type `string` instead of a string literal; it infers `Record<string, unknown>` so after narrowing, you won't get a type error on any string key, including strings you didn't test with `hasOwnProperty`. I think that's what you're hinting at with the sentence about edge-cases, but I think this should be spelled out explicitly.

Comment: yeah there are plenty of edge cases here, many of which could be addressed by increasingly complex signatures, but I don't know if that's worth it.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your own wrapper function around hasOwnProperty that does type narrowing.

This way you don't have to fiddle with the built in types and do type merging if you don't want to pollute the built in types.

```
function hasOwnProperty<T, K extends PropertyKey>(
    obj: T,
    prop: K
): obj is T & Record<K, unknown> {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
}
```

I found this solution here:
[TypeScript type narrowing not working when looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849097/typescript-type-narrowing-not-working-when-looping)

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that it makes property value `unknown`.

Comment: `!hasOwnProperty()` will give you weird type errors https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcA8AVANIgaUQFMAPKYsAE3UQAUAnOAB2IagE8DiOA+ACgBQiRHABGAKwBciPMMTMmzGQUEBKGeImIYtbIgBkiAErEIcBlUwF84ANZg4AdzC9EAb3kNiUEAyQA8pJmUAB0inBQkRysoWjoAS6MLGycoRCoADaZ-Fr4EcxqANyCAL6CgqCQsAgKIOjIycw4McQC8loy7ogA2nY8MuhQDDBgAOYAujLYrT0TiKW48gWDw6NjSyIAblkgxNOt6h7yMMCI-ACE8bmS+UpqasciIlo9BfMAvL0TJSLlL5I3koJuF6sh+DtMntil4fH4kFoSuVKuBoPAkMwwU0AHIWAC2WRarHaAOkHl6-Q4qxG4ymslm80WyyU1PWm0QkL2B1YR08IlO5wuQQkIXCTCinFi8USYCaqQ46SyOTyCnujz5z1e70QXzmvwWHUB71BDQhu2IMJE3l8-lEkiRgiAA

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy your example breaks because you try to use string as Prop. Doing `!hasOwnProperty()` with a string prop will eliminate all keys from the obj leaving just the never type in its place.

Answer (score 0):

For me, an object merge works like this:

```
const total = (action.hasOwnProperty("total")) ? 
        {...{total: defavlt}, ...action}.total : defavlt
```

or the short way:

```
const total = {...{total: defavlt}, ...action}.total
```

Comment: do you think this answers the question "Why does Typescript treat `object.hasOwnProperty("key")` as essentially different from `"key" in object`" ?

Comment: You're right. This is just another way to avoid the TS2339 error, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes here looking for a complete answer, it's possible to type the method and not lose out on any typing information

```
interface Object {
  hasOwnProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(this: T, key: K): this is T & {[Key in K]: T[Key]};
}
```