# Property does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: typescript

I am getting various different data structures from external sources. In `get()` i am checking for `undefined` and `existence` of the property, but still getting [compiler errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhMwAWBTaBvAUNaADgE4CWAbmAC6YC2YBAXHPQDwSWkB2A5gDTQB7AEYArdMEoA%20ANw480YAM7siAVwkCiACgCU2efkqoSEAHR0C0ALzRO6AO7MCbDiR79hYiZN2z8AXzl8AgECVXBqWHotVVUSABMmFTduHSYhAQEQdDBOfXx8AHpC6FMy6G50SkoU6DBoACkAZQB5ADlBUXFKaAAzIgEaaAhBhwwidANobJ70AA9qIk4wEAARKjAmT27rbH8-ApJe6Bi4%20OsbAHIwIWAy00u9XAKC%20cXltY3drAAiITAiD8mD8AEIAQQASj9%20D8IOgoCQlEDoLEEoEXv5oOgQHDoEctCizhdoD94uhevcfk8pvg3uglit1pR6jZfr1MsifgAxFotaEkuEIpFMVHxdEFYqlcojGi0TSYbG4o4we5TTGKzDPF5Yhb0j5MlnYP5gABenPBAC1%20bD4RBEZxkaLxQEpkYTOZ6KY4ZRTgl%20HSGZ9mToDvhFMosuhTCABNwtAH9RsQ1MJpRVEtoBxVOgDoF5JUfaKkq4eNSXjNoBMICFlJgbG6zBZTAXffE9AAfdvYS6Cu1KS5MTjhED7KZHE5Vmtw0yoSAteycAAKAwI9Mo8C0Pdt9seZe1qfTeUnSmnvftoegzsrVUP0Eul1zOH8QA).

Is there a quick fix for that as we are just prototyping at the moment ?

```
class MyCache {
  private map: Map<string, object>;

  constructor() {
    this.map = new Map<string, object>();
  }

  populateMap(uuid: string): boolean {
    // ... getting a JSON object from somewhere
    let externalData: object = {};
    if (uuid == 'abc...') {
      externalData = {"bar": "BAR", "session": uuid}
    } else if( uuid == "def...") {
      externalData = {"foo": "FOO", "session": uuid}
    // ... some more else ifs ...
    } else {
      externalData = {"baz": "BAZ", "session": uuid}
    }
    this.map.set(uuid, externalData);
    console.log(externalData);
    return true;
  }

  get(uuid: string) {
    let response = this.map.get(uuid) || {'session': null};
    if (response.hasOwnProperty('session')) {
      return response.session;
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Property 'session' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

Comment: Declare interface for `externalData`, if this is dynamic then you can declare it as `let externalData: { [key: string]: any } = {};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, type `object` is too general. I think it is better to use `Record<string, unknown>`.
Please see [ts eslint rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md):

Unsafe:

```js
//bad
const lowerObj: object = {};
```

Safe:

```js
// good
const lowerObj: Record<string, unknown> = {};
```

Using `hasOwnProperty` is ok, but using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, "bar")` is much better. See [eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins).

[Here](https://v8.dev/features/object-has-own) you can find recent optimization of V8 engine regarding using `hasOwnProperty`.

You can find more typings for `hasOwnProperty` in [my article](https://catchts.com/FP-style)

Hence, this code should be ok:

```js
class MyCache {
    private map: Map<string, Record<string, unknown>>;

    constructor() {
        this.map = new Map<string, Record<string, unknown>>();
    }

    populateMap(uuid: string): boolean {
        // ... getting a JSON Record<string, unknown> from somewhere
        let externalData: Record<string, unknown> = {};
        if (uuid == 'abc...') {
            externalData = { "bar": "BAR", "session": uuid }
        } else if (uuid == "def...") {
            externalData = { "foo": "FOO", "session": uuid }
            // ... some more else ifs ...
        } else {
            externalData = { "baz": "BAZ", "session": uuid }
        }
        this.map.set(uuid, externalData);
        console.log(externalData);
        return true;
    }

    get(uuid: string) {
        let response = this.map.get(uuid) || { 'session': null };
        if (response.hasOwnProperty('session')) {
            return response.session;
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhMwAWBTaBvAUNf0ADgE4CWAbmAC6YC2YhAXHAwDwRVkB2A5gDTQASumAB7YgBN2nUrwEBXLgGsuogO5cAfJoDcOPATFcOxecCriAFAEpsBggSqpSEAHT1C0ALzQu6NSyE0tz8QiLiUiayoYoq6lqaNnoOAL76DoSihPLgNLAMlvLypBLMUbzWzABGoqIg6GBcdg4OAPSt0K5d0DzoVFTR0GDQAFIAygDyAHJhYpLB0QrKqhqa0ABmxKK00BDb-hjE6PYt9VTQ6AAeNMRcYCAAItRgzMJzkTJy0LErWt7YKWSLXwpHW0EKxQk3h8AHIwFVgF1XDDbLhgcCrjc7o9nv8sNAAERVMDEAnMAkAIQAgoICQICRB0FBSKIuGTvpDoGl0VyLiBGdBQeCiiVoYSJOh1kiCaiTjzMehbvcnlRhj58QT1rV2QSAGITCZ0wmM5ms9kiqHcnkEdqdbp7Wh0cSYdD8zCgmBIuUEFJ8gVo634BVKnGqvGE4kALx11IAWkaGUyICy2cwLVzvfgrcCnC53AxXIyqBCSgJg9iVWBrEDgUY9vVXCBRDxLOXlc9q5noEcqPJbtBOPJ0DWMydesWLWVPjxZTyzt2mZljJgfLm3B5XOOSxJbAAfXfYaAwk3J1kw5hcHIgLkjhxCyxHCBLxmuVCQCYaAAKW0Iiqo8EsY8kxTFFZ0DBde37R9n3QQtgNZW8fS7Hs%20yaGEYRHNIUiAA)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `Object` instead of `object` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464634/difference-between-object-and-object-in-typescript)
2. Use `'key' in obj` instead of `hasOwnProperty` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195129/why-does-typescript-treat-object-hasownpropertykey-as-essentially-differen)

```
class MyCache {
    private map: Map<string, Object>;

    constructor() {
        this.map = new Map(); // No need for generic parameters, type is already set in the property declaration
    }

    get(uuid: string) {
        let response = this.map.get(uuid) || { 'session': null };
        if ('session' in response) {
            return response.session;
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Roberto Zvjerkovic please be aware that primitives are assignable to `Object`