# TS: type guard for ES Map, `if (map.has(key)) map.get(key)` is possibly undefined

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Basically I want an `key in obj` type guard but for ES Map.

When tsconfig.json `strict: true` is on, TS will error in this case:

```
const map = new Map<string, string>([["foo", "bar"]])

if (map.has("foo")) {
  map.get("foo").toLowerCase();
  // ~~~~~~~~~~ ERROR HERE
  // (method) Map<string, string>.get(key: string): string | undefined
  // Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
}
```

I know the reason is because TS's standard lib types ES Map as:

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    get(key: K): V | undefined;
    has(key: K): boolean;
}
```

We could manually suppress the error with `!` non-null assertion, but wouldn't it be nice that TS just gets smarter and saves us one keystroke? Because case like this is obviously correct.

I believe something can be done like with `Object.hasOwnProperty` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195129).

Comment: What about `const value = map.get(key); if (value !== undefined) { ..... }`

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I just figured it out and wrote an answer. It's quite an interesting finding to me.

Answer (score 0):

After many experiments I finally figured it out, and I'm very happy with the result! The answer is to augment `Map` interface like this:

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    has<P extends K>(key: P): this is { get(key: P): V } & this
    // funny thing: `& this` is the final piece of the puzzle
}

const map = new Map<string, string>([['foo', 'bar']])

map.get("foo").toLowerCase()
// ~~~~~~~~~~~
// without narrowing TS raises error as expected

if (map.has("foo")) {
    // after type guard narrowing, error goes away!
    var v = map.get("foo").toLowerCase()

    map.get("bar").toLowerCase()
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~
    // correctly catch unchecked case
}
```

Try it in [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLJwA4B4DSAaZANQD5kBvAKGWuQAs4BnLABWQgA9IQATB5HYgAoA1hACeALmTMAlFLC1gfJeWQBzCGBHipsqYWQBfZADJkCpVRoB6a8hgBXECDHnFINVIAGZiwy-IKgooMKBwADbIGMAQSMgA9jBuKBgOAF5p4RAUhhQUCPEgDGDIALaYyAC8yCAQAO5omFjFUKBqBC1tQgDa3QDkMPHxfQR9AEZwUH0AutMyeeUYAHQaWgBEg-FrMktg8QAy8XXQAMKMEILztsh1wArxDiUgk1BHbcgAKgDKyFBwShA+NBXlBkIw2OwMLFINw8sAkoJFkt6AxBBshtsZOQrNRrnAYJBQWAxFD1A5Jtwai83h4CMD4qC1PFAWC6nAxABCHHIABuk15VTKmBWmjRm22uwOR1O50ueRoQuWqzREygEr2h2OUDODAu8wV1wKUCg0PCrgQcDACFoyCc1tiokpFt1OSAA).

---

Inspired by [jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59200046/3617380), I came to this solution quite early. But it didn't work and I struggled to understand why. I seemed to me that, the type predicate failed to overload original function signature of `Map#get`.

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    has<P extends K>(key: P): this is { get(key: P): V }
}

// My theory of why this solution doesn't work.
// After narrowing it probably concludes to sth like:
interface Map<K, V> {
    get(key: K): V | undefined
    //  the order of above signature comes first
    // so it has high priority, that's my guess

    get<P extends K>(key: P): V
}
```

After lots of trial and error and detour to other suboptimal solutions, I noticed the popover hint of `map`'s inferred type after narrowing read:

[image: TS popover]

```
const map: Map<string, string> & {
    get(key: "foo"): string;
}
```

And the left/right ordering of the two operands of `&` operator struck me, so I went ahead to try adding at the end a `& this`, in hope of flipping around the order. And to my surprise it actually worked!

```
interface Map<K, V> {
    has<P extends K>(key: P): this is { get(key: P): V } & this //  the trick!
}

interface Map<K, V> {
    get<P extends K>(key: P): V

    // `& this` explicitly lower the priority of original signature
    get(key: K): V | undefined
}
```

Comment: This is really cool but somehow for me this interface replaces the Map interface entirely rather than extending it. Now I can only get when it is specifically tested with has first.

Comment: @SSlinky this work because of [interface merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces). Well I suspect the original `Map` interface (which we want to merge into) might not be accessible in the first place in your env for some reason. It’s possible to instruct TS to **not** include the standard declaration set.

Comment: It’d be helpful if you can share enough info for me to reproduce the behavior. I would definitely look into it.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks! Had to wrap it in a `declare global` because I was doing it in a module.

Comment: I see. Yeah the TS namespace thing is an easy footgun.

Comment: Usually I'll put this type of interface augmentation in a dedicated `global.d.ts` file and link to it in my `index.ts` with triple slash directive: `/// <reference path="global.d.ts" />`

Comment: I did try that but I'm writing a vscode extension. There is no index and it doesn't seem to like `*.d.ts`s - or at least it does until runtime where it splats because things don't load (or don't load in the right order).