# How can I make clear to TypeScript that optional numeric properties exist on two objects, and thus are comparable?

Tags: typescript

I need to sort an array of objects on an optional integer property `order` in the interval [0, n].  I'm using the JavaScript Array.prototype.sort() for this.

Since `order` is optional, I know that in my sort I have to confirm that the property exists on the two comparing objects.  But since `order` may equal 0 ( which is falsy), I can't check by the conditional clause `(a.order && b.order)` - which is sufficient to make TypeScript not complain.

I thought that I could use `(a.hasOwnProperty('order') && b.hasOwnProperty('order')`, but when I try that conditional clause, TypeScript is complaining that `Object is possible undefined. ts(2532)`.

So somehow `hasOwnProperty` isn't sufficient to make TypeScript believe that the property actually exists.

At the end of the day, the need is really:
How do I sort an array of object by an **optional** numeric field whose set of possible values may (actually - will) include 0.

But the question at hand is:
How do I make TypeScript understand that two objects do have the necessary property for comparison, if I can't use `a.property && b.property` because either a.property or b.property may be an existing, falsy value (namely, 0).

Edit to add:
The condition `(a.order >= 0 && b.order >= 0)` doesn't work for the same reason.

Comment: Does `typeof a.order === 'number' && typeof b.order === 'number'` work for you? See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnID2UAJtAPwBcyIArhgEbQDcuAvrrgG5xTJzV0ELAF4c+IqWjUAjO269kDQZmRi8BYmSjUADPNzAYyABRgAngAcIhY3AB0W6GpFiA5HUbQ3yAGS-kC2tbJUcpPld3TyYoNwBKcQIEQhAAZ0IAGwh7DMIAcxMHJz4AalDiuPx2IA)

Comment: Alternatively, use nullish coalescing operator `a.order ?? defaultOrder` in your sorting function.

Comment: @Lesiak - yes!  Your suggestion, using typeof, works!  Please feel free to add as an answer if you like and I'll mark as the accepted answer.  Also - if you have any insight into why hasOwnProperty doesn't work but typeof does, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options to work with your items in your sorting function:

**Use undefined type guard**

```
if (a.order !== undefined && b.order !== undefined) {
}
```

**Use typeof type guard**

```
if (typeof a.order === 'number' && typeof b.order === 'number') {
}
```

**Use a default order value if it does not exist**

```
const aSortOrder = a.order ?? DefaultValue
```

See [Advanced Types > Optional parameters and properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#optional-parameters-and-properties)

Note that `hasOwnProperty` is not implemented to work as a type guard

See [Why does Typescript treat `object.hasOwnProperty("key")` as essentially different from `"key" in object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195129/why-does-typescript-treat-object-hasownpropertykey-as-essentially-differen)